# Initiate Codable Model Class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, codable, decodable

Is it possible to initiate object which is codable. So that I can add values into variables.

Ex: let obj = MyClass() for NSObject class.
Something like this.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Codable init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280631/swift-codable-init)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
struct Person: Codable {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}

let p = Person(name: "Robert", age: 30)

print(p.name)
```