# Swift Codable init manually a property

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have `struct` that conforms to protocol `Codable`. Some properties are decoded from JSON fields so I use the `CodingKeys` enum for that. But there are few properties that are not in my JSON and I need to calculate them from decoded JSON properties. For example, if you get a `Zip code` from JSON, I want to calculate `City` from it.

I don't want `City` to be an optional String. So I try to calculate it right after my `Zip code` field is decoded from JSON.

```swift
struct Place: Codable {
   var name: String
   var zipcode: String
   // ... Lot of other properties decoded from JSON

   var city: String // This property has to be calulated after `zip code` is decoded

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name = "placeName"
      case zipcode = "NPA"
      // other properties from JSON
   }
}
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280631/swift-codable-init) solution to rewrite `init(from decoder: Decoder)`. But that means I need to manually write each property I need to decode. As I have a lot, I would prefer to let default init decoder does it job, and then add my code to calculate `City`.

Is there a way to do something like : call default init with decoder, then add some code ?

I was also thinking about computed property. But as calculating `City` from Zip code is quite lot of code, I don't want that it is always computed.

I need something like :

```swift
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
   // <- Call default init from decoder
   city = CityHelper.city(from: zipcode) // quite heavy code in there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would prefer to let default init decoder does it job, and then add my code to calculate City

Unfortunately you can't. It is currently all or nothing; you cannot treat the synthesized init as some sort of inheritance from super (as in your imagined `Call default init`).

> I was also thinking about computed property. But as calculating City from Zip code is quite lot of code, I don't want that it is always computed.

Use a lazy var property whose initializer calls a method that transforms zip to city. That way it is calculated, but just once. The zip will not change, so this is an acceptable compromise.

Or even better, use a reducer to transform the decoded struct (with zip) into a completely different struct (with city).

Comment: It looks like a good compromise in that case, yes! But that means first time this property is accessed, it could freeze a bit while it is calculated. And of course, later it won't be anymore. That's why I wanted to calculate everything when data is decoded from JSON / loaded.

Comment: That's exactly why I said a reducer was better. Download, decode, and reduce. All done.

Comment: Yep, I think my comment was right before your edit ^^ Could you provide me a link about that "reducer" solution or an example? I don't figure out how it works.

Comment: This just means you have a way of turning one struct into another struct. You can call that a reducer or a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but it needs to use `class` instead of `struct`.

I store decoded properties in a parent class. Then I extend this class and add calculated properties in it.

As it is not possible to extend `struct`, I had to use `class`. Maybe it is a first step to a better solution and it can help anyone find something better.

```swift
class DecodedPlace: Codable {
    var name: String
    var zipcode: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "placeName"
        case zipcode = "NPA"
    }
}

class Place: DecodedPlace {
    var city: String

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        city = "" // Default value just to call super.init.
        
        try super.init(from: decoder)
        
        city = CityHelper.city(from: zipcode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok misread at first. Here's something I think could help: use willSet or didSet on zip to then compute the city perhaps? Not sure if that gets you around not having a default value but this code will only run if the zipcode changes

```
struct Place: Codable {
   var name: String
    var zipcode: String{
        didSet{
            //do something after zip is set like calculate city?
        }
        willSet{
            //do something before zip is set.
        }
    }
   // ... Lot of other properties decoded from JSON

   var city: String // This property has to be calulated after `zip code` is decoded

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name = "placeName"
      case zipcode = "NPA"
      // other properties from JSON
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't want to compile because 'Type 'Place' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable''. It is because my property var city:String does not have a default value. I've tried setting city property as optional, but it doesn't work. didSet is not called on init?

Comment: "didSet is not called on init" Correct.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a computed property that relies on the zip to return a city. So you'd have to figure out the logic of how to map zip back to city with some method but here's a simple example I cooked up:

```
struct Rectangle : Codable{
        var width : Float
        var height : Float
        
        var area : Float{
            return width * height
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
let myRect = Rectangle(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
 print(myRect.area)
```

Result:
25.0

Comment: Look at the last paragraph of the question. A simple computed property won't do.

Comment: Thank you. But with that solution your area property is calculated each time you call it. As my code for "city from zip code" is quite heavy, I don't want to use a computed property.

Comment: Ok fair point. See my other solution using didSet/willSet